# Managing connection pools using Semaphores (Java)

Tags: java, connection-pooling, semaphore

I maintain a connection pool of size N and have semaphore of size N controlling access to each of the connection in the pool. The application acquires a semaphore when trying to send data across and releases it on receiving a response or a socket time out.

There is a background thread running within the connection pool which sends periodic heartbeats for each connection. Now if a heartbeat fails then that connection is closed and an effort is made to create a new one. What I want to make sure is as connection is opened and closed in the pool, I want the permits to be increased and decreased so that it directly reflects the number of connections in the pool. I can reduce the permits using the reducePermits(m) API but to increase, is calling release() (even when none has been acquired) multiple times on the semaphore the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, `release()` and `release(int)` are the methods to use to increase the number of available permits. The only reason `reducePermits(int)` exists is to provide a non-blocking means to reduce the number of available permits. `release` is non-blocking anyway, so an `increasePermits` function would be completely redundant.